# How to free SSL certificates on Debian 6 squeeze with Apache

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, lets-encrypt, mono, certbot

I'm looking for a way to use free SSL certificates in Apache running in Debian 6 squeeze.

I tried to use Lets-Encrypt

running

```
./certbot-auto --apache certonly --no-bootstrap
```

throws error

```
WARNING: couldn't find Python 2.7+ to check for updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/version.py", line 140, in __cmp__
    compare = cmp(self.version, other.version)
AttributeError: StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version'
```

I tried to install python 2.7 in Sqeeze using

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

but this throws error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssl : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5) but it is not installable
 python-pip : Depends: python-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1) but it is not going to be installed
 wkhtmltox : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to use free SSL certificates in sqeeze with Apache ?

Squeeze has also Mono last version installed from sources. Maybe some .NET or Mono ACME client can used.

Comment: Debian Squeeze is much, much too old to run certbot. Not to mention it has been EOL for quite some time. You will need to upgrade to a currently supported Linux distribution.

Comment: Squeeze server has large number of users and different heavily used applications. Upgrade is huge amount of work. I'm looking for a way to avoid it.

Comment: The upgrade you're looking to avoid is already more than three years overdue. You won't be able to avoid it much longer.

Comment: Why it cannot avoided ? acme.sh script works OK in squeeze. I compiled latest openssl and mono from sources and they also work OK. Is it possible to do automatic upgrade from squeeze to latest using `apt-get dist-upgrade` or will this cause server to stop working.

Comment: You must update because you don't have any security update on squeeze, have a look here: https://wiki.debian.org/fr/DebianReleases . You server is completely opened to any security fault that may have been discovered since support stopped... The update should be thoroughly tested before it's done on any production server....

Comment: Ports 80 for http, 443 for https, 22 for ssh and 5432 for Postgres are opened. Can you provide link to discovered security fault which can used ? I dont know any security fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try acme.sh shell script instead (https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh). I haven't good experience with Certbot on such old distributions, but acme.sh worked quite good for me. Or upgrade your OS to newer version (how @Michael Hampton already said in his comment), but it could be hard sometimes or customers don't want to pay for :)